# Firebase function nodemailer Office365

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, nodemailer, firebase-cloud-functions

Estou utilizando o firebase function para acionar o nodemailer e enviar um email.

Utilizando o gmail eu obtive sucesso, porém com o Outlook365 não funciona.

No transporter eu faço desta forma:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: 'outlook.office365.com',
    port: 25,
    secure: true, // use TLS
    auth: {
        user: 'meuemail',
        pass: 'minhasenha'
    },
    tls: {
        // do not fail on invalid certs
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
}));
```

Já tentei em outras portas, utilizando o `service: "Outlook365"` mas não obtive sucesso.

O console me retorna o seguinte erro

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND outlook.office365.com outlook.office365.com:587
at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
code: 'ECONNECTION',
errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'outlook.office365.com',
host: 'outlook.office365.com',
port: 587,
command: 'CONN'
```

Desde já, grato pela ajuda.